# Como passar argumentos por valor no Python?

Tags: python, operadores, passagem-por-valor

```
def somentenumeros(entrada):
    try:
        int(entrada)
        return True
    except:
        return False

while True:
    cpf = input('Digite seu CPF ou digite os nove primeiros digitos ')
    if somentenumeros(cpf) == False or len(cpf)!= 9 or len(cpf) != 11:
        print('Erro. O valor digitado era inválido.')
    else:
        break
```

Dessa maneira, acredito que venha por referência por padrão, o `entrada` é convertido para inteiro quando eu não quero. Como faço para que o parâmetro `entrada` seja por valor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este problema relatado na pergunta não existe, o código só falha porque a condição está errada.

Existem outros problema mais à frente no código que não é o foco desta pergunta.

```
def somentenumeros(entrada):
    try:
        int(entrada)
        return True
    except:
        return False

while True:
    cpf = input('Digite seu CPF ou digite os nove primeiros digitos ')
    if not somentenumeros(cpf) or (len(cpf)!= 9 and len(cpf) != 11):
        print('Erro. O valor digitado era inválido.')
    else:
        break
print(cpf)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/M5slYz). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ykecnwoh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Typing/Relational.py).

Comment: Podemos conversar sobre estes problemas no chat? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54792/discussion-between-miguel-and-vinicius

Comment: Editei a pergunta para ter o código adequado para testar. Sempre procure fazer um [mcve] na pergunta para permitir que as pessoas te ajudem melhor. Se o fizer, talvez ache o erro por conta própria no meio do processo. Faça códigos aos poucos, uma responsabilidade de cada vez. Se fizer mais de uma e der problema, teste individualmente. O erro não aconteceu por desconhecimento da linguagem em si, até porque conhece outras e a lógica é a mesma, ele ocorreu por não ter adotado uma boa estratégia de desenvolvimento e desconhecer como depurar código errado. É isto que precisa estudar.

Answer (score 4):

#### Na teoria:

Uma pesquisa básica na internet, encontrei esta [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/534383/1452488):

> Python passes **references-to-objects by value** (like Java), and everything in Python is an object. This sounds simple, but then you will notice that some data types seem to exhibit pass-by-value characteristics, while others seem to act like pass-by-reference... what's the deal?
>
> It is important to understand **mutable** and **immutable** objects. Some objects, like strings, tuples, and numbers, are immutable. Altering them inside a function/method will create a new instance and the original instance outside the function/method is not changed. Other objects, like lists and dictionaries are mutable, which means you can change the object in-place. Therefore, altering an object inside a function/method will also change the original object outside.

Em tradução livre:

> Python passa referência à objetos por valor (como Java) e tudo no Python é um objeto. Isto parece simples, mas então notará que alguns tipos de dados parecem ter sido passadas por valor enquanto outros parecem ser passados por referência.
>
> É importante compreender o que são objetos mutáveis e imutáveis. Alguns objetos, como strings, tuplas e números são imutáveis. Alterá-los dentro de uma função criará uma nova instância do tipo referido, mantendo a instância original sem alterações. Outros objetos, como listas e dicionários são mutáveis, o que significa que você alterações no objeto dentro da função serão refletidas ao objeto externo.

#### Na prática:

Considere o seguinte código:

```
value = 1

def function (value):

  # Exibe as informações da variável antes da mutação
  print("Dentro da função, antes da mutação:", type(value), id(value), value)

  # Mutação da variável
  value = 0

  # Exibe as informações da variável depois da mutação
  print("Dentro da função, depois da mutação:", type(value), id(value), value)


# Exibe as informações da variável antes da função
print("Fora da função, antes da mutação:", type(value), id(value), value)

# Chama a função
function(value)

# Exibe as informações da variável depois da função
print("Fora da função, depois da mutação:", type(value), id(value), value)
```

A respectiva saída é:

```
Fora da função, antes da mutação:    <type 'int'> 17355096 1
Dentro da função, antes da mutação:  <type 'int'> 17355096 1
Dentro da função, depois da mutação: <type 'int'> 17355120 0
Fora da função, depois da mutação:   <type 'int'> 17355096 1
```

Perceba que o valor da terceira coluna, resultado da função `id`, é o endereço de memória da variável. Antes da função, a variável está em 17355096; quando passado por parâmetro à função, mantém-se o endereço, pois é passado na verdade uma referência ao objeto; após a mutação, o endereço passa a ser 17355120, pois o tipo `int` é imutável e alterá-lo gera uma nova instância; por fim, fora da função, o endereço se manteve o original, assim como seu valor 1.

Executando o mesmo código para uma lista:

```
value = [1]

def function (value):

  # Exibe as informações da variável antes da mutação
  print("Dentro da função, antes da mutação:", type(value), id(value), value)

  # Mutação da variável
  value.append(2)

  # Exibe as informações da variável depois da mutação
  print("Dentro da função, depois da mutação:", type(value), id(value), value)


# Exibe as informações da variável antes da função
print("Fora da função, antes da mutação:", type(value), id(value), value)

# Chama a função
function(value)

# Exibe as informações da variável depois da função
print("Fora da função, depois da mutação:", type(value), id(value), value)
```

Tem-se a saída:

```
Fora da função, antes da mutação:    <type 'list'> 140643613447880 [1]
Dentro da função, antes da mutação:  <type 'list'> 140643613447880 [1]
Dentro da função, depois da mutação: <type 'list'> 140643613447880 [1, 2]
Fora da função, depois da mutação:   <type 'list'> 140643613447880 [1, 2]
```

Perceba que o endereço de memória se manteve o mesmo em todos os passos e o valor alterado dentro da função foi refletido para fora da mesma. Isso aconteceu porque o tipo `list` é mutável e alterações no objeto não geram novas instâncias.

Comment: O problema da questão (apesar do titulo) não era exatamente este, mas achei a explicação boa e interessante. Bem explicado

Comment: Pois é, vi nos comentários depois, mas achei válido manter a resposta.