# isinstance() não produz o resultado esperado após uma entrada de dados

Tags: python, if, tipagem

Fiz o seguinte exemplo de fatorial usando função `isinstance()`.

```
  def factory(n):
       if not isinstance(n,int) or n<0:
            print('NAO E NUMERO INTEIRO VALIDO:\n')
            return None
       if n==0:
            return 1
       else:
            return n*factory(n-1)
```

Agora quando eu tento fazer códigos simples para entender o funcionamento dessa função não estou conseguindo chegar em um resultado, se eu digito numero inteiro ele nem entra no `if`. Gostaria de entender melhor o `isinstance()`

```
  x=input()

  if isinstance(x,int):
       print("ok!")
```

Comment: input returna str, vc tem que converter x = int(input())

Comment: claro!, nossa que pergunta besta. Muito obrigado !!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Está correto, se você olhar a [documentação de `input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) verá que ela resulta em uma *string*, então não faria o menor sentido entrar nesse `if`.

Provavelmente você vai querer transformar  isso em um inteiro com a função [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), o que garantirá que é um dado do tipo `int` e o `if` passa não fazer sentido. Infelizmente a [cultura de Python é de deixar uma exceção explodir](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/314111/101) se não conseguir fazer a conversão, então a forma correta de lidar com isso é ter um `try-except` no código para verificar se deu certo ou não ([exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/187873/101)), e talvez seja isso que deseja de fato.

Certamente [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) não é para o que deseja, ela faz mais sentido quando tem hierarquia de tipos no que quer verificar, ou pelo menos quando tem real motivo para não saber qual é o tipo exato do dado , se você sabe que tipo ele é o seu uso não faz sentido.

Tenho visto muito as pessoas confundirem tipo do dado com o conteúdo dele. As pessoas muitas vezes querem que uma *string* que tenha só dígitos numéricos seja um número, e se não tiver um ponto deve ser um inteiro. Isso é um grave erro. De fato toda entrada e saída de dados com inteiração com o usuário é feito por textos, que por acaso são dígitos numéricos, mas não são números. Número existe por si só e são usados para cálculos. A entrada e saída é só uma representação textual do número que humanos entendem melhor, mas é diferente do que o computador sabe lidar. É só um acaso que esse texto tenha só dígitos numéricos. Quando entra dados pelo console você precisa converter para número para usar como número, e  pode ser que esta operação não seja bem sucedida se o texto não estiver bem formado. E o `print()` também converte o número para um texto, mesmo que você não perceba, mas é um texto impresso ali e não o número, que seria incompreensível para um humano.

Answer (score 1):

Victor, como você pode observar na [documentação do isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance), ele recebe dois parâmetros em seus parêntesis: o primeiro é a variável ou dado que você quer verificar e o segundo o tipo que você quer se certificar que ela seja. No caso de `isinstance(x,int)`, ele irá verificar se x é do tipo int; se sim, retornará TRUE e entrará no if.

Sua dúvida deve ser: eu digito um número inteiro no `input()` e o `isinstance()` retorna falso? **Sim** e a justificativa é que o input sempre retorna uma string. Se você digitar um número int e quiser utilizar ele no `isinstance()` o que você deve fazer é forçá-lo a ser um número usando int().

Você pode tentar o seguinte:

```
x = int(input())
```

Como você está estudando, faça um teste:

```
x = input()
print(type(x))
```

retornará 'str'

```
y = int(input())
print(type(y))
```

retornará 'int'

Espero ter ajudado!